# Reading from stdin and printing to stdout in Ruby

Tags: ruby, arrays, string, newline

This question is kinda simple (don't be so harsh with me), but I can't get a code-beautiful solution. I have the following code:

```
ARGF.each_line do |line|
  arguments = line.split(',')
    arguments.each do |task|
    puts "#{task} result"
  end
end
```

It simply read from the standard input numbers. I use it this way:

```
echo "1,2,3" | ruby prog.rb
```

The output desired is

```
1 result
2 result
3 result
```

But the actual output is

```
1 result
2 result
3
 result
```

It seems like there's a newline character introduced. I'm skipping something?

Comment: `puts task.inspect` would have shown that there was a newline in `task`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Each `line` ends in a newline character, so splitting on commas in your example means that the last token is `3\n`. Printing this prints `3` and then a newline.

Try using

```
arguments = line.chomp.split(',')
```

To remove the trailing newlines before splitting.

Answer (score 1):

Your stdin input includes a trailing newline character. Try calling `line.chomp!` as the first instruction in your `each_line` block.